# Returning after 30-day stay in Abu Dhabi

Tags: us-citizens, visas-on-arrival, uae

I carry a valid US passport. I have a 30-day stay stamped at Abu Dhabi airport.  After 30 days, can I leave the UAE for a few days, then come back to Abu Dhabi and get another 30-day stay visa?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, you can: unlike the EU, the UAE does not publish any "X days in Y days" limits. But you may get a few questions about why, and if you keep doing it, you will be suspected of working there and eventually denied entry.

Comment: To be pedantic, it's Schengen which does this, not the EU.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier: To be even more pedantic, the entity that prepares and publishes the Schengen rules _is_ the EU, even though the rules don't apply to all of its members (and do apply to a few countries that aren't members). "Schengen" is not something that "does" anything; it is merely a name for a particular area of EU legislation.

Comment: Ok, fair point. Nevertheless, it's important because the rules don't (for example) apply to the UK/Ireland. But I accept your chastisement :)

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**  The easiest / cheapest way for an American national is to cross the border by car into Oman, and return.  It will restart the 30-days.  You can make it your monthly trip to someplace nice and nearby like Beirut (etc.)

However, as an aside, I recommend you spend some time in Oman, whether camping or staying at the Shangri-La or wherever, it's beautiful!  Then, return to get your tourist visa.

EDIT As requested: Things can always change; in 2010 Canadians could no longer do the "visa run," like they used to.  This was due to a [dispute about airlines](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-12088449) that resulted in changes in their visa structure.  I commented only to suggest that you check the latest news when it comes to UAE.

Comment: I should caveat that it's important you try to get a more permanent visa, because you never know when something might kick-off and you've got an invalid visa (e.g. - the Canadian airline dispute in 2010)

Comment: That caveat should be in your answer, not as a comment.  Comments can disappear and aren't necessarily read. (Also, it would be useful to give a link to some coverage of the 2010 dispute you mention: I for one have no idea what it is.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is frequently done by Americans and others.  You can take a car to Oman, or a cheap flight out of the UAE and back.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a reference to rules that say you can ?

Comment: I think the rules might have changed in January 2016, I'm not sure.  Looking around I found this:    Multiple entry visit visa is valid for 6 months and the applicant must exit the country within 14 days after arrival. Furthermore, the applicant must initially enter the country on a single entry visit visa and apply for multiple entry visit visa within 5 days of arrival.  [link](http://www.dsoa.ae/en/services/visit-visas/)

Comment: Awesome, it's best to edit your answer and include that info